# OIDC with JWT in HTTP-only cookie instead of HTTP Authorization bearer header

Tags: authentication, cookies, csrf, oauth2, openid-connect

I'm exploring the possibility of implementing OpenID Connect (OIDC) with an HTTP-only cookie to keep my frontend code completely authentication-agnostic, instead of passing the Authorization header around through Javascript code.
The idea behind this is that front-end developers don't have to worry about authentication.

- My frontend is a SPA build with Javascript and HTML and consists only of static files.
- My backend is a REST API, with no UI.
- I want to use OIDC Implicit Flow but my Authorization Server sets the HTTP-Only cookie with access_token JWT, instead of passing the token back as a query parameter.
- I believe that by using an HTTP-Only cookie, I can make Implicit flow as secure as Authorization Code with PKCE flow because the token is not exposed as a URL parameter when redirecting back to the client after a successful login.

I think HTTP-only Cookie as a JWT carrier is possible because all my client applications, resource servers, and the login screen are on the same origin. HTTP-Only cookies are also invisible to Javascript code, therefore they are inherently secure against XSS attacks.
Especially I want my frontend-applications not to use `auth-token` grant, replacing it with `access_code` being set in the JWT cookie already, so that first call to `/token` endpoint could be skipped, which I believe removes a lot of complexity from the frontend part.

The only thing my front-end could do is intercept handling HTTP responses from AJAX calls using Fetch API (I could achieve it with a simple wrapper around `fetch()` function, I could provide it in a mini JS library that frontend developers should use).
So that 401 and 403 status codes would redirect users to the login screen.

What are the security implications of such a setup? Specifically, I am interested in how to handle:

- CSRF-tokens, I see some resources recommend using `SameSite=Strict` cookie attribute, but is it enough? I probably still want to use CSRF-token, but how could I validate on the resource-server side?
- Similarly, how should I deal with Refresh-Tokens? Should I still have a `/token` endpoint with `refresh_token` grant-type support? Should I also keep the refresh tokens in HTTP-only cookie in that case?

Please indicate any security issues this kind of setup has, or suggest alternative ways.
Please consider that my application frontend is completely static, and there is no way to generate HTML or Javascript in the backend.

Comment: can you motivate why you want to deviate from the Authentication Bearer token. Especially since its part of the standards for authentication, and using cookies isn't. 

I suspect you are less agnostic with your choice than you surmise.

Comment: As I updated in the question "HTTP-Only cookies are also invisible to Javascript code, therefore they are inherently secure against XSS attacks". So my JS code cannot see the JWT, and this enforces delegation of security to the Backend. Also, I want to be able to switch between Opaque token and JWT whenever needed, so I need to prevent frontend developers from accessing and parsing JWT from their JS because I don't want them to assume that the JWT payload is there.

Comment: Also I some online resources advice: "don’t store a JWT in local storage (or session storage). If any of the third-party scripts you include in your page is compromised, it can access all your users’ tokens.
To keep them secure, you should always store JWTs inside an httpOnly cookie." source: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jwt-token-where-store-browser-deepak-jha/

Comment: [Answer on how to store JWT in browser](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/257247/78777) also suggests that HTTP-Only cookies are "likely the best option you get if taken care of properly".

Comment: it all depends on your threat model...  and on how you implement your system. things like ServiceWorkers can abstract away a lot of the risks you wish to mitigate I suspect. (for example)

Comment: If "all my client applications, resource servers, and the login screen are on the same origin" then why use OIDC at all? Is this just for future-proofing in case you want to use external auth (or provide auth to external apps) at some point? Otherwise, this sounds like the typical case for classic local authentication, which is much less complicated (and thus at less risk of being poorly implemented) than OIDC. OIDC is for external auth (federated authentication or SSO), which doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: Even though the applications on the same origin, they are completely separate, they don't share a common sessionStorage. And many resource servers do not have any means to share the session. Therefore JWT would allow servers to check if the request is authorized without making a round trip to any shared session storage or introspection endpoint. Another reason for using OAuth2 is that resource servers could make use of the OAuth2 library available for their platform.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about JWT, I guess you are talking about the `id_token` which is the only token which is *required* to be a JWT by OpenID Connect.

You can actually do better than that. Your frontend actually does not need to keep the `id_token` and, when using the authorization code flow, does not need to ever see the `id_token`, `access_token` and `refresh_token` at all. All your frontend has to see is the authorization code.

What you can do is store a (HTTP only) session cookie in the frontend (eg. `JSESSIONID`, `PHPSESSID`):

1. When you start the OpenID Connect dance, the backend generates a `state`, `nonce`, `code_verifier` and `code_challenge` and associates all of that to the session.
2. Your backend generates an authentication request.
3. At some point, the OpenID provider sends back the `state` parameter and authorization code to your application.
4. Your backend checks that the state is the one which is stored in the session, does several additional verifications.
5. Your **backend** exchanges the `code` it received with the `id_token`, `access_token` and `refresh_token`.
6. Your backend generates a new session and associates these tokens with this new session.

As you see, in this workflow, the frontend:

- never sees any `id_token`, `access_token`, `refresh_token`;
- sees the authorization code;
- might see the `state` and `code_challenge` (unless [Pushed Authorization Requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9126) which you should use if you can).

In this example, the session ID was stored as a HTTP only cookie but it could be stored through some other mechanism if needed.

> I think HTTP-only Cookie as a JWT carrier is possible because all my client applications, **resource servers**

You are talking about resource servers, are you really talking about OpenID Connect of about OAuth in general?

Comment: This answer is for a scenario where the backend and frontend are the same app. My backend is a REST API with no UI, and the frontend is a Javascript-based SPA, which acts as a client in OIDC Implicit flow. However, I am willing to make certain deviations from the standard in the frontend, taking advantage of having all my applications on the same origin host. My backend acts as a resource-server and I want it to use access_token JWT to authorize to it. The only difference from a normal OIDC resource-server is that instead of using HTTP header it would use a cookie.

Comment: Given that I am on single origin, I assume it is safe to use Implicit flow, therefore I don't need to exchange authorizatins_code to access_token as explained in step #5